# Overloaded operator must take zero or one argument

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Yes, this question has been asked before, but the problem was that the operator was a member function and that's not the case here. These are my files:

**minmax.h**

```
#ifndef MINMAX_H
#define MINMAX_H

class MinMax
{
private:
    int m_nMin;
    int m_nMax;

public:
    MinMax(int nMin, int nMax);

    int GetMin() { return m_nMin; }
    int GetMax() { return m_nMax; }

    friend MinMax operator+(const MinMax &cM1, const MinMax &cM2);
    friend MinMax operator+(const MinMax &cM, int nValue);
    friend MinMax operator+(int nValue, const MinMax &cM);
};

#endif // MINMAX_H
```

**minmax.cpp**

```
#include "minmax.h"

MinMax::MinMax(int nMin, int nMax)
{
    m_nMin = nMin;
    m_nMax = nMax;
}

MinMax MinMax::operator+(const MinMax &cM1, const MinMax &cM2)
{
    //compare member variables to find minimum and maximum values between all 4
    int nMin = cM1.m_nMin < cM2.m_nMin ? cM1.m_nMin : cM2.m_nMin;
    int nMax = cM1.m_nMax > cM2.m_nMax ? cM1.m_nMax : cM2.m_nMax;

    //return a new MinMax object with above values
    return MinMax(nMin, nMax);
}

MinMax MinMax::operator+(const MinMax &cM, int nValue)
{
    //compare member variables with integer value
    //to see if integer value is less or greater than any of them
    int nMin = cM.m_nMin < nValue ? cM.m_nMin : nValue;
    int nMax = cM.m_nMax > nValue ? cM.m_nMax : nValue;

    return MinMax(nMin, nMax);
}

MinMax MinMax::operator+(int nValue, const MinMax %cM)
{
    //switch argument places and pass them to previous operator version
    //this avoids duplicate code by reusing function
    return (cM + nValue);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "minmax.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MinMax cM1(10, 15);
    MinMax cM2(8, 11);
    MinMax cM3(3, 12);

    //sum all MinMax objects to find min and max values between all of them
    MinMax cMFinal = cM1 + 5 + 8 + cM2 + cM3 + 16;
    cout << cMFinal.GetMin() << ", " << cMFinal.GetMax() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The message reads `error: 'MinMax MinMax::operator+(const MinMax&, const MinMax&)' must take either zero or one argument`

Comment: You shouldn't define them with `MinMax::` at the start.

Comment: None of these operators are members of `MinMax`, so you cannot define them as such. A `friend` function is not a member of the class.

Comment: This question has been asked in _every_ configuration.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl: You shouldn't answer questions in comments...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit All the other ones must be pretty well buried then because I've looked at several answers and none helped.

Comment: `MinMax cMFinal = cM1 + 5 + 8 + cM2 + cM3 + 16;` I would hate to see this code in a project. Not a good use of operator overloading. Stick with functions. Try looking at `std::minmax` or `std::minmax_element`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To turn my comment into an answer:

You're defining your function as a member function by putting `MinMax::` in front of it, so they **are** member functions.

```
MinMax MinMax::operator+(const MinMax &cM, int nValue)
{  // should be operator+ without the MinMax:: at the front.

    //compare member variables with integer value
    //to see if integer value is less or greater than any of them
    int nMin = cM.m_nMin < nValue ? cM.m_nMin : nValue;
    int nMax = cM.m_nMax > nValue ? cM.m_nMax : nValue;

    return MinMax(nMin, nMax);
}
```

you can see it working [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0a0db8f3ca9c2e1)

Answer (score 2):

As you've said, they are not member functions.

Therefore, in their definitions, the `MinMax::` prefix is incorrect and should not be there.